# Saving Class Type info to file for later use

Tags: java, android

As you know, passing class types is important when programming Android applications.
One simple example is using an Intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
```

So it'll be kind of useful in some situations if I can save the class type info to a file for later use, for instance, after reboot.

```
void saveClassTypeInfo(Class<?> classType, String filename) {

String str = null;

// Some job with classType

FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fos.write(str.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

If I could save in a certain way like above, then I would be able to put it back to an Intent like this in the future.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, restoredClassInfoFromFile);
```

How I can achieve this kind of job? Because `Class<?>` is not an object, I don't know where to start at all.

**[EDIT]
.class is an object too, so we can save it just like saving an object.**

Comment: are you looking for something like creating a class from a name (string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using `ObjectOutputStream` here `SaveState` is your Custom class

```
public static void saveData(SaveState instance){
ObjectOutput out;
try {
     File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "appSaveState.ser");
     out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
     out.writeObject(instance);
     out.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static SaveState loadData(){
 ObjectInput in;
 SaveState ss=null;
 try {
     in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("appSaveState.ser"));       
     ss=(SaveState) in.readObject();
     in.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
 return ss;
}
```

Full Tutorial write to File available [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/)
And Read Object from File [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-object-from-file-in-java/)

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. Woks like a charm! Thanks a million!!

Comment: I never thought .class is an object, very ashamed.. Thanks to you, now I understand what it means. The code works great in my app so far, a big thanks again!